# JavaScript with Type Safety?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've tried using TypeScript but then can't reference it in HTML because it needs to somehow automatically get turned into JavaScript somehow using a TypeScript Compiler.

I want to bypass TypeScript altogether now to avoid this problem and all its complexity - is there a way to get the type-safety of TypeScript directly in JavaScript?  I can make do without classes but what I would like is to be able to have a function declaration like this:
`export function View(canvasId: string): string[] { }`

Comment: I dont think you can. What do you mean reference in html?

Comment: So it's a script tag like this: `<script type="module" src="/js/Main.ts"></script>` but if I run it, the browser console reports: `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Comment: _"is there a way to get the type-safety of TypeScript directly in JavaScript?"_ - JS itself is weakly and dynamically typed, that's why TypeScript exists. Transpile the TS to JS with the compiler, which also does the type checking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe With which compiler?  Visual Studio doesn't do this automatically...

Comment: Up to you. You could use _the_ compiler, `tsc`. Or Babel, esbuild, ... [Read the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html)

Comment: But how?  This is the whole complexity I'm trying to avoid!  Do I need a post-build script to call tsc.exe?  Does that mean I have to include tsc.exe in the project?  How do I make it so that GIT doesn't start checking these generated files into source control without excluding original js files?

Comment: You need to ignore the generated js file from git and everytime you update the ts you rebuild the js with tsc

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is ridiculous - it's the equivalent of if you had to track down and integrate the Rosyln compiler to build C#!

Comment: Typescript is never javascript and browser doesnt support it if you want to use type safety in js you need to do it... And you dont need to integrate tsc in browser

Comment: If you feel the costs outweigh the benefits, don't use TS. Again it's up to you. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html suggests you _can_ integrate it into VS.

Answer (score 2):

No, until you wait for the current Type proposal to be added to js, see https://github.com/tc39/notes/blob/main/meetings/2023-03/mar-22.md#type-annotations-proposal-update, but even then it's still only optional.

> I want to bypass TypeScript altogether now to avoid this problem and all its complexity

I simply would not recommand that, nowadays everyone uses build tools for pretty much any web apps that they are building and after the initial repository setup you typically start a file watcher which compiles your TypeScript files.

If you are writing js code which you just want to run locally you can also try out bun, it can directly execute TypeScript without any extra configuration, see https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/typescript.

Finally, I recommend just using vite to create the necessary directory structure and then as a framework you just choose `Vanilla` with `TypeScript`

```
npm install -g vite
npm create vite@latest

√ Select a framework: » Vanilla
√ Select a variant: » TypeScript

  cd test-tmp
  npm install
  npm run dev
```